# Binary/CRCdivision remainder

Tags: java, binary, division, crc

I have tried to create a code that calculates the remainder of CRC error detection/correction in Java, but I don't know what the difference between it and binary division.

When:

```
    BigInteger G = new BigInteger("1001", 2);
    BigInteger M = new BigInteger("101110", 2);
    BigInteger R = M.remainder(G);
```

R value will be : 1 
but when i manually calculate the CRC Remainder it will be : 011

what is the difference here, and is there any method or algorithm to calculate CRC remainder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remainder for a CRC is that of a *polynomial* division. You treat the bits of the dividend and divisor as the coefficients of polynomials over the [Galois Field of two elements (called GF(2))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2)). In that field, addition becomes exclusive-or, and multiplication becomes and. 1+1 is 0, not 2, since there is no 2, only 0 and 1.

If you do the polynomial division you should remember from high school, you'll get the answer. It's easy to do over GF(2) with just the bits:

```
          101
      --------
1001 / 101110
       1001
       ------
         1010
         1001
         ----
           11
```

So we get the quotient `101` and remainder `11`.